# Wx.Python non-Blocking GUI starting and stopping script/module

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, module, wxpython

I want to be able to run and stop script/module from my GUI without blocking it. I learned some basic things about threading and running "simple" long tasks inside GUI code. However all the examples are about simple `while` or `for` loop that can bi aborted. In most cases it is some kind of counting.

So the question is: How to run/stop external script/module with wx.python based GUI? The script is nothing specific it can be any kind of long task.

Here is the basic wx.Python example code!

```
import wx

class MyApp (wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title = 'Example')
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title ,style = (wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CLIP_CHILDREN))

        button1 = wx.Button(self,-1,'Start')
        button2 = wx.Button(self,-1, 'Stop')
        self.gauge1 = wx.Button(self, -1)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        box.Add(button1,1, wx.ALL, 10)
        box.Add(button2,1, wx.ALL, 10)
        box.Add(self.gauge1,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,10)

        self.SetSizer(box, wx.EXPAND)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, button2)

    def OnStart(self,e):
        pass


    def OnStop(self,e):
        pass


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I do not have any problem with counting. And I will not use a long running task in simple form. I will use some external script so I only need a way to start or stop my script with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that you are calling will need some mechanism for quitting cleanly or you will just have to deal with the mess. I would use Python's subprocess module to launch the external script and then use something like psutil (https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) to kill it if I needed to. That would require you to grab the process id (pid) with subprocess and keep track of it so you could kill it later.

I wrote up an example of using psutil in wxPython here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/13/wxpython-creating-your-own-cross-platform-process-monitor-with-psutil/